# jenkins build error - Non-resolvable parent POM for Could not find artifact and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

My project is a sprintboot web project and the structure looks like this:

```
/myFirstProject
 +-----------/pom.xml
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWvRa.jpg)

I can build and run the project in my local environment.

```
      .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.1.3)

2023-09-16T22:45:17.754+10:00  INFO 21304 --- [           main] c.e.m.MyFirstProjectApplication          : Starting MyFirstProjectApplication using Java 18.0.2 with PID 21304 (E:\DevOps\myFirstProject\target\classes started by 92351 in E:\DevOps\myFirstProject)
2023-09-16T22:45:17.759+10:00  INFO 21304 --- [           main] c.e.m.MyFirstProjectApplication          : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-09-16T22:45:18.956+10:00  INFO 21304 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2023-09-16T22:45:18.965+10:00  INFO 21304 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-09-16T22:45:18.965+10:00  INFO 21304 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.12]
2023-09-16T22:45:19.076+10:00  INFO 21304 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-09-16T22:45:19.078+10:00  INFO 21304 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1246 ms
2023-09-16T22:45:19.598+10:00  INFO 21304 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2023-09-16T22:45:19.614+10:00  INFO 21304 --- [           main] c.e.m.MyFirstProjectApplication          : Started MyFirstProjectApplication in 2.293 seconds (process running for 2.719)
```

On my local machine (windows) i can build my project from / with:

```
mvn -f myFirstProject/pom.xml clean install
```

having no error, even with an empty repository.

But jenkins (linux) is not able to do this.

```
Started by user root
Running as SYSTEM
Building in workspace /var/jenkins_home/workspace/firstproject
The recommended git tool is: NONE
No credentials specified
 > git rev-parse --resolve-git-dir /var/jenkins_home/workspace/firstproject/.git # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url http://*.*.*.*:8989/syukaygroup/firstproject.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from http://*.*.*.*:8989/syukaygroup/firstproject.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
 > git --version # 'git version 2.39.2'
 > git fetch --tags --force --progress -- http://*.*.*.*:0000/syukaygroup/firstproject.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/main^{commit} # timeout=10
Checking out Revision 41b05fce2fe6857cddd9486569a07da596428534 (refs/remotes/origin/main)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f 41b05fce2fe6857cddd9486569a07da596428534 # timeout=10
Commit message: "commit"
 > git rev-list --no-walk 41b05fce2fe6857cddd9486569a07da596428534 # timeout=10
[firstproject] $ /var/jenkins_home/maven/bin/mvn clean package -Dmaven.test.skip=true -U clean install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...

Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/3.1.3/spring-boot-starter-parent-3.1.3.pom
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for com.example:myFirstProject:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:3.1.3 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): transfer failed for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/3.1.3/spring-boot-starter-parent-3.1.3.pom and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM @ line 5, column 10
 @ 
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project com.example:myFirstProject:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT (/var/jenkins_home/workspace/firstproject/pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM for com.example:myFirstProject:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:3.1.3 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): transfer failed for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/3.1.3/spring-boot-starter-parent-3.1.3.pom and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM @ line 5, column 10: No trusted certificate found -> [Help 2]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException
Build step 'Invoke top-level Maven targets' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

So here's what's in my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>myFirstProject</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>myFirstProject</name>
    <description>myFirstProject</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${parent.version}</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

So does somebody has a suggestion what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Your PC has access to a Maven repository but Jenkins has not.

Comment: Is your Jenkins in windows too? How are you building with jenkins? Why your pom.xml is not in the root? That is the standard!!

Comment: BTW: That project will never work, because Spring Boot 3+ required JDK17 as minimum... not JDK8!!

Comment: Based on that: ` No trusted certificate found ` my assumption is that you are using a very old JDK?

Comment: @JRichardsz My jenkins is in the linux server. I build jenkins with command "mvn -f myFirstProject/pom.xml clean install".

Comment: @BTW On my local machine, I can build the project with jdk8 and I download JDK1.8 under the jenkins in the remote linux server. But I just can't build the project in the remote linux server.

Answer (score 0):

The parent Pom you refer to is not present in the repositories this maven instance can access.

Be certain to use the latest version of maven and plugins to build.

Answer (score 0):

## Short explanation

Spring Boot 3 required java 11. Try with it and share us the details

## Detailed explanation

I tried to replicate your error. This is the corner stone to fix a bug, If a bug is not reproducible in another machine, the ticket will be closed. If this answer cannot help you, your have a work: reproduce the error in another machine and share the exact steps

- Validated template: https://github.com/jrichardsz/spring-boot-templates/tree/master/000-hello-world
- docker container reproducing your environment:

`docker run -it -v $(pwd):/app -w /app maven:3.6.3-jdk-8 bash`

[image]

### Stable template

Using my template, I was able to compile it using `mvn clean package`, so everything is ok with java, maven, spring boot, linux, etc

### Your pom.xml

Overriding my pom with yours, I got an error not exactly as yours but I think it helps:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.11.0:compile (default-compile) on project myFirstProject: Fatal error compiling: invalid flag: --release -> [Help 1]
```

So, why my pom works but not your?

### Compare poms

Comparing I see you are using **3.1.3** version but I was using **2.1.1.RELEASE**

Using my version in your pom, the error disappeared.

### Why 3.1.3 don't work

Checking the maven repository

[image]

I validated that your pom works with the latest "2" version (2.7.15) but it fails since "3" version.

Researching I found this: https://spring.io/blog/2022/05/24/preparing-for-spring-boot-3-0

[image]

> So maybe your error is related to the usage of JDK 8 but spring-boot requires JDK 11